# Child component observable not initialized with ngIf

Tags: angular, angular5

I have CompA. CompA has as a child CompB. CompB has an ngIf condition and based on an observable which is shared between CompA and CompB it is loading some data. When I set this condition to be true I call next on the observable from CompA but data are not shown CompB is not yet initialized so that it subscribes to the observable
here is the code:

```
//compA.html
<div>
...
<button (click)="switchToCompB()">Show</button>
<compB *ngIf="compBVisible"></compB>

</div>


//compA.ts
public switchToCompB() {
        this.compBVisible = !this.compBVisible;

        if (this.compBVisible)
            this.sharedObservable.next(message);
}

// compB.ts
ngOnInit(){
    this.sharedObservable.subscribe(message => {
        ...some code here
    })
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can bind mesaage in CompB and get the data in compB using `@Input` decorator

Answer (score 0):

You should use @Input event binding.

```
// compA.html
<button (click)="switchToCompB()">Show</button>
<compB *ngIf="compBVisible" [myInput] = "someInputValue"></compB>

//compB.ts

export class SomeClass{
 @Input myInput: any;
 ngOnInit(){
 // some code here to execute during component initialisation
 }

 ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges){

 //some code here to be executed whenever the input value changes
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed Subject to BehaviorSubject. In that way a value is always there for susbcribers. So even when CompB is subscribed after the condition is set it always get the latest value